# Matrix function of two arguments.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am looking for resources and books about matrix function but specifically with more than one matrix as an argument. For example $F(A,B)=lnA+AB^2$ as a generalisation of $f(x,y)=lnx+xy^2$. Theorems, formal treatment and calculations. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you looking for more precisely? Continuity, derivative? Else?

Comment: More specifically I try to use something similar as the $MDM−1$ theorem to do a particular calculation. If it can be generalized for more arguments I wanna see how..If not I need to read the theory to find a different way. Does this make some sense?